# Replace part of a string with new value

Tags: c#

I've got a scenario, wherein i need to replace the string literal with new text.

For example, if my string is "01HW128120", i will first check if the text contains "01HW" If yes, then replace that with the string "MachineID-".

So eventually i wanted "01HW128120" to be "MachineID-128120". Sometimes i do get the string as "1001HW128120" - In this case also i require to replace the "1001HW" with "MachineID-"
I tried the below code snippet, but this does not work to my expectation.

```
string sampleText = "01HW128120";
if(sampleText.Contains("01HW"))
  sampleText = sampleText.Replace("01HW","MachineID-");
```

Any suggestion would be of great help to me.

Comment: you may want to describe how the result differed from your expectation

Comment: What was your expectation ? The code seems fine to me and does exactly what you want.

Comment: Looks and works fine for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Few Possible Search Values

If there are only a few possible combinations, you can simply do multiple tests:

```
string value = "01HW128120";
string replacement = "MachineID-";

if( value.Contains( "01HW" ) ) {
    value = value.Replace( "01HW", replacement );
}
else if( value.Contains( "1001HW" ) ) {
    value = value.Replace( "1001HW", replacement );
}

Assert.AreEqual( "MachineID-128120", value );
```

### Many Possible Search Values

Of course, this approach quickly becomes unwieldy if you have a large quantity of possibilities. Another approach is to keep all of the search strings in a list.

```
string value = "01HW128120";
string replacement = "MachineID-";

var tokens = new List<string> {
    "01HW", 
    "1001HW"

    // n number of potential search strings here
};

foreach( string token in tokens ) {
    if( value.Contains( token ) ) {
        value = value.Replace( token, replacement );
        break;
    }
}
```

### "Smarter" Matching

A regular expression is well-suited for string replacement if you have a manageable number of search strings but you perhaps need not-exact matches, case-insensitivity, lookaround, or capturing of values to insert into the replaced string.

An extremely simple regex which meets your stated requirements: `1001HW|01HW`.

Demo: http://regexr.com?34djm

A slightly smarter regex: `^\d{2,4}HW`

- Assert position at start of string
- Match 2-4 digits
- Match the value "HW" literally

See also: [Regex.Replace Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to replace everything up to `"01HW"` with `"MachineID-"`, you could use a generic regex:

```
sampleText = Regex.Replace(sampleText, "^.*01HW", "MachineID-");
```